# Upgrade networkx

Tags: installation, pip, version, networkx

On my laptop I have networkx 2.8.6

BUT on a cluster I am working on running

> $ pip3 install networkx==2.8.6

I get that there is no such version!

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
> networkx==2.8.6 (from versions: 0.34, 0.35, 0.35.1, 0.36, 0.37, 0.99,
> 1.0rc1, 1.0, 1.0.1, 1.1, 1.2rc1, 1.2, 1.3rc1, 1.3, 1.4rc1, 1.4, 1.5rc1, 1.5, 1.6rc1, 1.6, 1.7rc1, 1.7, 1.8rc1, 1.8, 1.8.1, 1.9rc1, 1.9, 1.9.1, 1.10rc2, 1.10, 1.11rc1, 1.11rc2, 1.11, 2.0, 2.1, 2.2rc1, 2.2, 2.3rc3, 2.3rc4, 2.3, 2.4rc1, 2.4rc2, 2.4, 2.5rc1, 2.5, 2.5.1)

What could be the problem?

Comment: What version of python 3 is on the cluster?  From `setup.py` of the github repo for networkx, [NetworkX 2.7+ requires Python 3.8 or later](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/9279be80efe674f44380a15d239ed9784fb70f9d/setup.py#L8)

Comment: 3.9.12 on laptop, 3.6.7 on the cluster ... So I guess that is the problem.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As noted by @Frodnar in the comment, `networkx>=2.7` requires `python>=3.8`.

Users with `conda` installed can create a custom environment with  an explicit `python` version, e.g.:

```bash
# create environment called nx_env
conda create -n nx_env -c conda-forge python=3.10 networkx=2.8

# after environment is created, activate it
conda activate nx_env
```

Answer (score 0):

I also managed to solve it as follows:

To install Python 3.8 locally I downloaded the source file (https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3815/) and compile it. I did this in directory in my home:

```
cd into extracted download
./configure --enable-optimizations
make -j8
./python -m venv path_to_venv
```